# Undefined return in $.get jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

*This question is already **answered** and **voted**. My edits are related to making it clearer and share some new knowledge acquired for other developers, **I'm not expecting new answers**.*

I'm reading an XML with jQuery, but when I try to show an alert it's fully working; however, when I try to return the value it always gives me a message that it's undefined.

```
function getText(value){

    var val;
    var lang;
    var location;
    lang=getLanguage();

    if (lang=='en')
        lang='';
    else
        lang+='.';

    location="resources/AppResources."+lang+'xml';

    $.get(location, function (xml) {
        $(xml).find("data").each(function () {
        
            var name=$(this).attr('name');

            if (name===value)
                return $(this).find('value').text();
        });
    });
    
}
```

This is the code that calls it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    alert(getText('AppTitle'));
});
```

If I add an alert in the return statement it shows me the value selected.

**Small update:**

As Arun P Johny explained in his answer, the missed part in my code was the [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) that are defined by Mozilla in this way:

> A callback function is a function passed into another function as an argument, which is then invoked inside the outer function to complete some kind of routine or action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a value from a async method, the easiest solution is to use a callback function like this one:

```
function getText(value, callback) {
    var val;
    var lang;
    var location;
    lang = getLanguage();

    if (lang == 'en') 
        lang = '';
    else 
        lang += '.';

    location = "resources/AppResources." + lang + 'xml';

    $.get(location, function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('data[name="' + value + '"]').each(function () {
            callback($(this).find('value').text());
        });
    });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getText('AppTitle', function(value){
        alert(value);
    })
});
```

Comment: @user2889347 read about Same Origin Policy